# Formation of tertiary alcohol with Ester and ONLY 1 equivalent of Grignard reagent

Tags: grignard-reagent

I don't understand how 2 methyl groups can be added to an ester to form a tertiary alcohol when I only have 1 equivalent of MeMgBr. Doesn't 1 equivalent mean that I only have 1 Methyl group that I can add (so only a ketone with 1 methyl group would be formed)?

Thank you

Comment: It's one methyl group *per molecule of ester starting material*; but there's nothing saying that they react in a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: Then what does the concept of 1 equivalent imply?

Comment: 1 equivalent just tells you how much you add to the reaction mixture; it doesn't tell you the ratio in which they react, either. To be clear, if you want the ester starting material to be *completely* consumed, you should probably add 2 equivalents (in fact, a real-life procedure will likely use even more than that, just to really make sure all of the ester reacts). But if you only add 1 equivalent of Grignard, then only half of the ester will react.

Comment: Thank you @orthocresol

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to ChemSE!. In most instances Grignard reagents react faster with ketones than with esters at their respective carbonyl groups. The rate constant for the reaction of the reagent with a ketone is much larger than the rate constant for reaction with an ester. The rate of the reactions is also a function of concentration of the substrates and Grignard reagent.
Historically, Grignard reagents were prepared *in situ*. The substrates are added dropwise to the Grignard reagent, which is referred to as the normal mode of addition. As the reagent reacts with the incoming ester, a ketone is formed in the presence of a sea of Grignard reagent. Even though the concentration of ketone is low, the Grignard reagent concentration is very high and there is no way that the ketone will survive. That is why the reaction of Grignard reagents with esters usually uses two equivalents of reagent to form a tertiary alcohol having two identical alkyl groups. An alternative mode of addition is inverse addition.
An example from the [chemical literature](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00802a040) will help to appreciate the difference between these two modes of addition. N-Methylindole is metallated with *n*-butyllithium to form lithium reagent **1**, which was prepared *in situ*. One equivalent of the reactive ester diethyl oxalate was added dropwise to one equivalent of the organolithium reagent with the expectation that α-keto ester **4** would be formed. However, the only products formed were α-diketone **2** and α-hydroxy ketone **3**. Clearly, α-ketoester **4** was formed but it could not survive in the presence of an excess of reagent. In this particular case it is the ester group of **4** that reacts with the reagent and not the ketone. This ester is particularly reactive and the ketone may well be sterically hindered. It is apparent that α-diketone **2** is the genesis of the α-hydroxyketone **3**.

[image]

When one equivalent of lithium reagent **1** was added dropwise to four equivalents of diethyl oxalate, the α-ketoester **4** was formed because there was always an excess of diethyl oxalate. Saponification of the crude ester produced α-keto acid **5** in 59% yield overall.